# How to limit which database objects are rendered in Django admin space

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django app which is used for tracking inventory of products at my company.

We have since expanded into multiple locations.

Now my goal is to create multiple admin spaces where the products that are shown limited by product location.

I have not found any good resources on the best way to do this. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

models.py

```
class dboinv_product(models.Model):
    pk_product_id = models.UUIDField(
        default = uuid.uuid4,
        primary_key=True,
        null=False
    )
    product_creation_time = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True
    )
    product_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=False
    )
    product_description = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        null=True
    )
    current_cost = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        null = True
    )
    current_qty = models.IntegerField(
        null=False
    )
    obsolete = models.BooleanField(
        null=True
    )
    fk_location_name = models.ForeignKey(
        dboinv_location,
        verbose_name="Location name",
        default='Boston',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

Admin.py

```
@admin.register(dboinv_product)
class dboinv_productAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CreateProductForm
pass
```

for example if a user were to go to 'Boston/admin', they should only be able to see the products where 'fk_location_name' = 'Boston'

NOTE: I want to retain original admin space for myself, but I will make a seperate URL so that the  website has no link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned of a method within the django admin `get_queryset(self, request)`

After extending the user model with a OneToOne relationship, I can associated a location with a user, and use the request object to view the user's location, and tailor the queryset to match location using the get_queryset method